# what is the correct syntax to declare ports in squid?

Tags: squid

what is the correct syntax to declare ports in squid?

In [Squid official](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/) says (edited):

```
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 563     # snews
```

But [debian](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/ch05s02.en.html) says:

```
acl Safe_ports port 443 563     # https, snews
```

Question: I would like to know if the following rules would be correct. Example:

```
acl Safe_ports port 80 21 443 563 1025-65535
acl SSL_ports port 80 21 443 563 1025-65535
```

Thanks in advanced

Comment: The Squid doc you linked to makes it clear that both forms are allowed.

Comment: ok. thanks. I just wanted to make sure